# How to create/make rounded corner buttons in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, button, styles, wpf-controls

I need to create a **rounded corner glossy button** in WPF. Can anyone please explain me what steps are needed?

Comment: The basics for rounded corners are using the Border or Rectangle class, and the Radius property

Comment: @KierenJohnstone sure, but the Button class doesn't have those properties.  So how do you do it for a Button?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have to create your own ControlTemplate for the Button. just have a look at the sample

created a style called RoundCorner and inside that i changed rather created my own new  Control Template with Border (CornerRadius=8) for round corner and some background and other trigger effect. If you have or know Expression Blend it can be done very easily.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCorner" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid x:Name="grid">
                    <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" 
                                                        ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#00000000"/>
                                <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
                            </RadialGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          TextElement.FontWeight="Bold">
                        </ContentPresenter>
                    </Border>

                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.496,1.052">
                                    <RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <TransformGroup>
                                            <ScaleTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" ScaleX="1.5" ScaleY="1.5"/>
                                            <TranslateTransform X="0.02" Y="0.3"/>
                                        </TransformGroup>
                                    </RadialGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#00000000" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FF303030" Offset="0.3"/>
                                </RadialGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#FF33962B"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**Using**

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource RoundCorner}" 
        Height="25" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Content="Show" 
        Width="100" 
        Margin="5" />
```

Comment: I put the border outside of Grid which have a rectangle background when mouseover. Thank of pointing out border element need to be inside Grid and ContentPresenter has alignment setting as well.

Comment: Holy crap.  All that just to get Rounded corners?

Comment: Also, it turns my buttons very dark and fails to give them rounded corners. (Using WPF 4.0) :(

Comment: @BrianSlugs83 This is what makes WPF such a pleasure to work with.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I don't think it's **all** needed. The replier made it easy for him and copied that atrocity from automatically generated code using Blend. That's why he got all that *holy excrement* and that's why it's so poorly formatted. In my view, the reply should be accepted but definitely not upvoted. However, feel free to stip down to the basics of the roundness (omitting the coloring, hovering etc.) and post it yourself. I'd definitely give you +1 for that.

Comment: Deleting WPF form => Insert WebView => border-radius: 8px => Presto

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer and did not deserve all these votes. Other answers are better

Answer (score 228):

I know this post is super old, but I have an answer that's surprisingly missing from the above and is also much simpler than most.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

Since the default ControlTemplate for the Button control uses a Border element, adding a style for Border to the Button's resources applies that style to that Border. This lets you add rounded corners without having to make your own ControlTemplate and without any code. It also works on all varieties of Button (e.g. ToggleButton and RepeatButton).

Comment: This solution is so simple and elegant. I don't quite understand how it works, since the Button object doesn't have a Border, but I love it anyway.

Comment: @Rod It works because Button *does* have a border. Button's ControlTemplate contains a Border control and displays everything else inside of it.

Comment: Oh, OK @KeithStein, I was under an misunderstanding concerning the Button control. Thank you!

Comment: Surprisingly, it doesn't work on Windows Embedded 7. I am trying to find the default ControlTemplate for button

Comment: This solution is good, but the solution Crandel posted is a bit better.

Answer (score 68):

The simplest solution without changing the default style is:

```
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="RoundButton">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Then just define your button like this:

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource RoundButton}" />
```

Comment: Style.Resources was the bit I had missed. Was trying Button.Resources in a Style in App.Xaml to no avail. Perfect.

Answer (score 32):

This is more of a minimal control template to get a button with rounded corners, however you will not have any hover or click visual effects. But you can add these to the control template as needed. I was working with a dark background, hence the white background.

```
<Style x:Key="RoundedButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <Border CornerRadius="15" Background="White" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I used the control template from the following blog post as my starting point:
http://shihac-sharp.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/button-with-rounded-corners-in-wpf.html

Answer (score 11):

You can try this...........

```
 <Border BorderBrush="Black" Name="MyBorder"  
            Height="78" 
            Background="Red" 
            Width="74" 
            CornerRadius="3">
        <Button Width="{Binding MyBorder.Width}" 
                Height="{Binding MyBorder.Height}" 
                Content="Hi" Background="Red"/>
    </Border>
```

Comment: easier to implement.

Comment: This works but the background of the button must be Transparent

Comment: Kind of works. The hit test for the button causes you to lose the round ness.

Comment: Hmm. I will find a solution for that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 10):

despite the fact years have gone, i thing it's interesting to think about different way to approach it.

The way to recreate all the button template is an excellent way if you want to change everything but it's demoralizing for the beginner or if you just want to round corner of the button. It's true you don't have to change everything but at least you will must change events...

The way to modify "border" design in the button.resources is excellent too, if you are a beginner but it can be very boring to change all your buttons if you want to raise your design with more parameters.

There is a solution with a foot in both camps:

Put this code in window/page resources:

```
<Style TargetType="Border" x:Key="RoundMe">
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
</Style>
```

Then for the buttons:

```
  <Button.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource RoundMe}"/>
    </Button.Resources>
```

Answer (score 8):

The most simple way is

```
<Button Content="OK"
            Background="#D73C46"
            Foreground="White"
            BorderThickness="0"
            Margin="10,25,10,5"
            Width="275"
            Height="34"
            FontSize="12"
            Click="CloseWindow"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
            </Style>
        </Button.Resources>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 4):

As alternative, you can code something like this:

```
    <Border 
            x:Name="borderBtnAdd"
            BorderThickness="1" 
            BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
            CornerRadius="360" 
            Height="30" 
            Margin="0,10,10,0" 
            VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="30">
        <Image x:Name="btnAdd"
               Source="Recursos/Images/ic_add_circle_outline_black_24dp_2x.png"
               Width="{Binding borderBtnAdd.Width}" Height="{Binding borderBtnAdd.Height}"/>
    </Border>
```

The "Button" will look something like this:

[image: How it could looks like]

You could set any other content instead of the image.

Answer (score 3):

This is an adapted version of @Kishore Kumar 's answer that is simpler and more closely matches the default button style and colours. It also fixes the issue that his "IsPressed" trigger is in the wrong order and will never be executed since the "MouseOver" will take precedent:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="#707070" BorderThickness="1" Background="LightGray">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                      TextElement.FontWeight="Normal">
                            </ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border" Value="#BEE6FD"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#3C7FB1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#2C628B"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="grid" Value="0.25"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
```

Answer (score 3):

When first starting I always disliked how a snippet of code with no explanation of location was given. So, there's this:

```
<Window x:Class ...>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="btnRound" TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="Select" Click="Select_Click" Style="{StaticResource btnRound}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="10,2"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

in your app.xaml add this part of style :

```
   <Application.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement" x:Key="VisibleAnimation">
  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
  <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="10"/>
  <Setter Property="Height" Value="700"></Setter>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Visibility" Value="Visible">
      <Trigger.EnterActions>
    <BeginStoryboard>
      <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                         From="0.0" To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
       </Storyboard>
     </BeginStoryboard>
   </Trigger.EnterActions>
   </Trigger>
 </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="BTNCORNER">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border CornerRadius="7,7,7,7" Background="White"    BorderBrush="#ccc" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" >
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"   ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding  Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding  VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    </Application.Resources>
```

Button

```
 <Button x:Name="loginButton"  
         Style="{StaticResource BTNCORNER}"   
         Margin="50,20,20,20"  
         Click="loginButton_Click" 
         FontSize="20" Width="93" Height="42"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attached properties for setting button border radius (also the same will work for textboxes).

Create class for attached property

```
public class CornerRadiusSetter
{
    public static CornerRadius GetCornerRadius(DependencyObject obj) => (CornerRadius)obj.GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty);

    public static void SetCornerRadius(DependencyObject obj, CornerRadius value) => obj.SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value);

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof(Border.CornerRadius), typeof(CornerRadius),
            typeof(CornerRadiusSetter), new UIPropertyMetadata(new CornerRadius(), CornerRadiusChangedCallback));

    public static void CornerRadiusChangedCallback(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;

        if (control == null) return;

        control.Loaded -= Control_Loaded;
        control.Loaded += Control_Loaded;
    }

    private static void Control_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control control = sender as Control;

        if (control == null || control.Template == null) return;

        control.ApplyTemplate();

        Border border = control.Template.FindName("border", control) as Border;

        if (border == null) return;

        border.CornerRadius = GetCornerRadius(control);
    }
}
```

Then you can use attached property syntax for multiple buttons without style duplicates:

```
<Button local:CornerRadiusSetter.CornerRadius="10">Click me!</Button>
<Button local:CornerRadiusSetter.CornerRadius="5, 0, 0, 5">Click me!</Button>
<Button local:CornerRadiusSetter.CornerRadius="3, 20, 8, 15">Click me!</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Button x:Name="btnBack" Grid.Row="2" Width="300"
                        Click="btnBack_Click">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="#463190">
                            <TextBlock Text="Retry" Foreground="White" 
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"                                           
                                       Margin="0,5,0,0"
                                       Height="40"
                                       FontSize="20"></TextBlock>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: What happened to `ContentPresenter`?

Answer (score 0):

Well the best way to get round corners fast and with standard animation is to create a copy of the control template with Blend.
Once you get a copy set the corner radius on the Grid tag and you should be able to have your control with full animation functionality and applyable to any button control. look this is the code:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonControlTemplate" TargetType="Button">        
    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          CornerRadius="8,8,8,8">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPointerOver}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPointerOver}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundPressed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushPressed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundPressed}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <!--<Border CornerRadius="8,8,8,8"
                        Background="#002060"
                        BorderBrush="Red"
                        BorderThickness="2">-->
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw"/>
        <!--</Border>-->
    </Grid>        
</ControlTemplate>
```

I also edited the VisualState="PointerOver" specifically at Storyboard.TargetName="BorderBrush", because its ThemeResource get squared corners whenever PointerOver triggers.

Then you should be able to apply it to your control style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentControl" x:Key="ButtonLoginStyle"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource CommonLoginStyleMobile}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#002060"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ButtonControlTemplate}"/>        
</Style>
```

So you can apply your styles to any Button.

Comment: How does this work - `<Grid>` does not have a `CornerRadius` property? This is referring to a WPF Windows application, not a Universal Windows application - they are different.

Comment: Yes, you are right i was talking about UWP. But anyways you could still apply the concept to WPF. Just edit the control template created by blend and edit their properties to fit your needs, that way you wouldnt need to start from 0.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is long-since answered, I used an alternative approach that people might find simpler than any of these solutions (even Keith Stein's excellent answer).  So I'm posting it in case it might help anyone.

You can achieve rounded corners on a button without having to write any XAML (other than a Style, once) and without having to replace the template or set/change any other properties.  Just use an EventSetter in your style for the button's "Loaded" event and change it in code-behind.

(And if your style lives in a separate Resource Dictionary XAML file, then you can put the event code in a [code-behind file for your resource dictionary](https://tyrrrz.me/blog/code-behind-for-resourcedictionary-in-wpf).)

I do it like this:

Xaml Style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
    <EventSetter Event="Loaded"                   Handler="ButtonLoaded"/>
</Style>
```

Code-Behind:

```
public partial class ButtonStyles
{
    private void ButtonLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(sender is Button b))
            return;

        // Find the first top-level border we can.

        Border border = default;
        for (var i = 0; null == border && i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(b); ++i)
            border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(b, i) as Border;

        // If we found it, set its corner radius how we want.  

        if (border != null)
            border.CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(3);
    }
}
```

If you had to add the code-behind file to an existing resource dictionary xaml file, you can even have the code-behind file automatically appear underneath that XAML file in the Visual Studio Solution if you want.  In a .NET Core project, just give it appropriate corresponding name (e.g if the resource Dictionary is "MyDictionary.xaml", name the code-behind file "MyDictionary.xaml.cs").  In a .NET Framework project, you need to [edit the .csproj file in XML mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32762069/5869304)

Answer (score 0):

I know its a old question but if you are looking to make the button on c# instead of xaml you can set the `CornerRadius` that will round your button.

```
Button buttonRouded = new Button
{
   CornerRadius = 10,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

for anyone who wonders why their xaml doesn't work when they put in the button rounded code, check the previous line to see if it ends with `/>`, and take out the / if it does.