# Round the corners of a button in Window.Resources WPF

Tags: wpf

I am very new to WPF. I've familiarized myself with `ControlTemplate`, `ContentPresenter`, and some other pieces, but I am struggling to create a button with rounded corners as defined from `Window.Resources` (or potentially a separate style file).

Anyways, when I add this to a `<Button/>` tag, I get a button with rounded corners:

```
<Button.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
    </Style>
</Button.Resources>
```

However, when I try to include it up in the `Window.Resources` the button will not apply the border style:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="roundbutton" TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
        <Border CornerRadius="5"/>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This doesn't look right to me, but I guess I don't know where to add the specification of `CornerRadius` such that it will apply to the button. I did see this post, [How to create/make rounded corner buttons in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6745663/how-to-create-make-rounded-corner-buttons-in-wpf) but it's a little over my head. I just want to round all the buttons in my application!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Border in your ControlTemplate is not visible, because you have neither set its Background, nor its BorderBrush.

You could have something like shown below. Note however that with a simple ControlTemplate like this a Button loses all the visualizations of its states, like *focused*, *mouse-over*, *pressed* etc.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="roundbutton" TargetType="Button">
    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
            CornerRadius="5">
        <ContentPresenter/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

You may instead just declare a default Button Style (i.e. a Style resource without `x:Key`) that applies your original Border Style like this:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: Gotcha, I see what you mean about losing all visualizations of its states. I also am realizing that I can add a style different than a template. I am guessing that in the link I referred to, that button was keeping most of its state visualizations? Is there a simpler way to stylize the button (maybe without a ControlTemplate) to have the rounded corners, without losing all the default behaviors/states it would have?

Comment: My apologies, I see there (in the other post) that @Crandel answered what I'm going after, though his isn't the accepted answer for some reason.

Comment: Please see the edited answer.